# Enum does not name type, (no cyclic dependecy)

Tags: c++, enums

I am facing a problem where compiler screams about enum not naming a type.
I looked here on other posts (enum does not name type), but most of them are because of cyclic dependency issue.

code in input/RegisteredKeyEventCallback.h

```
#pragma once

#include "UserDefinableInput.h"
#include "../Game/Other/CallBack/CallBack.h"
#include "../Containers/LinkedList/LinkedList.h"
#include "../HashFunctions/HashFunctions.h"

using namespace std;

class InputManager;

/**
* @brief structure for saving all callbacks that belong to one ID.
*/
struct RegisteredKeyEventCallback
{
    enum KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM
    {
        KEY_PRESS, /**< When key was released and is pressed. Fired only once */
        WHILE_KEY_DOWN, /**< Fired while the key is down. Multiple times */
        KEY_RELEASE, /**< When key was pressed and is released now. Fired only once */
        _NULL
    };

    /**
    * @brief Creates new empty instance
    */
    RegisteredKeyEventCallback();
    ~RegisteredKeyEventCallback();

  ...
};
```

hashfunctions.h

```
#pragma once
struct RegisteredKeyEventCallback;

struct KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM_Hasher
{
   size_t operator()(const RegisteredKeyEventCallback::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM& k) const;
};
```

Sorry if I am blind, but I can not see it. Cyclic dependecy should not be there, as I foward declare, and the hashfunctions.h I provided is all the code.

Still, getting compile error
error:  KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM in struct RegisteredKeyEventCallback does not name a type.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

### EDIT: Thank you for your advices, I managed to solve it thanks to you

code in input/RegisteredKeyEventCallback.h

```
#pragma once

#include "UserDefinableInput.h"
#include "../Game/Other/CallBack/CallBack.h"
#include "../Containers/LinkedList/LinkedList.h"
#include "../HashFunctions/HashFunctions.h"

using namespace std;

class InputManager;
struct HashFunctions; //<---------------------------
/**
* @brief structure for saving all callbacks that belong to one ID.
*/
```

HashFunctions.h

```
#pragma once

#include "../Input/RegisteredKeyEventCallback.h"

struct KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM_Hasher
{

    size_t operator()(const RegisteredKeyEventCallback::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM& k) const;
};
```

Comment: The forward declaration isn't enough to access `RegisteredKeyEventCallback::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you don't have a cyclic dependency, but that's not the problem here. The problem is that in `HashFunctions.h` the compiler doesn't know what `RegisteredKeyEventCallback::KEY_EVENT_TYPE_ENUM` is.

By making a forward declaration of the `RegisteredKeyEventCallback` class, you only make a forward declaration of the class itself, not its members. You need the full definition of the `RegisteredKeyEventCallback` class *and* its members in your `HashFunctions.h` header file, which means you will get a cyclic dependency that you need to solve some other way.